# Python Multiprocessing Pool starmap function gives a memory error

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, slurm

I am relatively new to multiprocessing with python, and here I want to use multiprocessing in order to speed up some computations. I am basically trying to just use `multiprocessing.Pool()` to group some processes together and then use `Pool.starmap()` because the worker function I have written requires multiple arguments. Here is the important part of my script that draws the error:

```
def worker(return_shape, det, l1, l2, iterate):
    
    calculation = np.zeros(return_shape)

    for combo in iterate:
        calculation[combo[0], combo[1], combo[2]] += np.histogram2d(l1[:, det, combo[1]], l2[:, combo[0], combo[2]], [np.arange(-0.5, 2, 1), np.arange(-0.5, 2, 1)])[0]

    return calculation


# these will be populated with data
covListP = np.zeros((int(1e5), 48, 50))
covListN = np.zeros((int(1e5), 48, 50))

combinations = [(i, j, k) for i, j, k in itertools.product(range(48), range(50),range(50))]

args = [((48, 50, 50, 2, 2), job, list1, list2, combinations) for job in range(cpu_count)]
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=cpu_count)
worker_out = pool.starmap(worker, args)
```

The error message I receive is the following:

```
File "corrOptions.py", line 109, in <module>
    fameCorr.fameCorr(FOLDER, CHUNK_SIZE, PATH, BN, BP, SYSNAME, SYSTYPE, ERG_THRESHOLD, TIME_UP_THRESHOLD, KINCUT_MODE, KINCUT_MIN, KINCUT_MAX, ADVANCED_MODES)
  File "/eoins/fame/corrFAME/fameCorr_v4.py", line 214, in fameCorr
    worker_out = pool.starmap(worker, args)
  File "/sw/arcts/centos7/python3.7-anaconda/2020.02/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 276, in starmap
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, starmapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "/sw/arcts/centos7/python3.7-anaconda/2020.02/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 657, in get
    raise self._value
  File "/sw/arcts/centos7/python3.7-anaconda/2020.02/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 431, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
  File "/sw/arcts/centos7/python3.7-anaconda/2020.02/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 206, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "/sw/arcts/centos7/python3.7-anaconda/2020.02/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 393, in _send_bytes
    header = struct.pack("!i", n)
struct.error: 'i' format requires -2147483648 <= number <= 2147483647
```

I have googled this error message and it seems that it has something to do with memory limits in python for different operating systems, which might be a little over my head. I am also running this code on a SLURM computing cluster, so I am unsure how to really get information about the OS on that. Overall, would anyone be able to shed some light on this error message or direct me towards somewhere I might find a solution?